# Alguien me puede ayudar con un programa en SHarpdevelop para guardar numeros no repetidos con un arreglo?

Tags: c#

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] elementos=new int [10];
            int i=1;//que empieze a guardar desde 0
            int numero=0;

            while (i<11)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Proporcione un elemento {0}",i);
                numero=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            i++;


            }


            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola rosa, bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad

Comment: si pero yo estoy utilizando sharpdevelop y ahi no hay contains

Answer (score 0):

En el ejemplo he cambiado el tipo de la variable **elementos**. En lugar de ser un array de enteros ahora es un ArrayList. Esto lo he hecho porque tiene el método 'Contains', que devuelve un booleano dependiendo de si el valor indicado está dentro del arraylist o no.

Como podrás ver, lo único que he añadido dentro del bucle es la siguiente condición:

```
    if (!elementos.Contains(numero))
        elementos.Add(numero);
```

Lo que hace es añadir el número seleccionado por el usuario siempre que no exista ya en el arraylist.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //int[] elementos = new int[10];
        ArrayList elementos = new ArrayList();
        int i = 1;//que empieze a guardar desde 0
        int numero = 0;

        while (i < 11)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Proporcione un elemento {0}", i);
            numero = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (!elementos.Contains(numero))
                elementos.Add(numero);

            i++;
        }

        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
```

Comment: pero si yo no quiero cambiar el tipo de variable

Comment: Puedes mirar el enlace que indica arriba @Xam

Answer (score 0):

mi método es similar a como lo resolvió zeross, sin embargo sigo utilizando el int[] elementos:

```
using System.Linq; //nota: Es importante agregar esto, de lo contrario no funciona.

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] elementos = new int[10];        
    int i = 1;//que empieze a guardar desde 0
    int numero = 0;

    while (i < 11)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Proporcione un elemento {0}", i);
        numero = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (!elementos.Contains<int>(numero))
        {
             elementos[i] = numero;
             i++;
        }            
    }

    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

De esta manera se utiliza el método Contains<> que viene siendo de System.Linq y al poner el i++ dentro del if se asegura que se pida nuevamente el número ya que el que se había ingresado está repetido.